# How can I show iAds throughout entire app?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

First of all, it seems frowned upon to have my iAds showing throughout my entire app.  Is it a bad thing to show them throughout the whole app?  Why/why not?

And my real question is, is it possible to add iAds to the whole app?  I am thinking I could add it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but I'm not sure exactly how to keep it as the topmost view.  Has anyone done this before?  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You First Question is a topic for discussion, so I am not getting into that.

For your real question, You can have one main/container ViewController and have one placeholder for child ViewController and one placeholder for iAds. You actual ViewControllers can be added to the main view controller using ViewController containment api. You can find more about ViewController containment here: [Creating Custom Container View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)